# AIR iOS app open Notification Center

Tags: ios, actionscript-3, air, ane

Has anyone made an ANE to do this yet? In iOS8 you can direct the user to the Notifications Center which would make it really handy for toggling Notifications

Comment: If you've got a reference to the documentation I'll have a look at adding it to ours.

Answer (score 0):

Never mind, I wrote my own ANE to open Setting on iOS. I'll make it available on Github when I get rid of this targeting build warning.